# Functor category between two small categories is not small?

Tags: category-theory

Let $C,D$ be two small categories, i.e. small sets of objects $O_C, O_D$ and small hom-sets $\mathrm{Hom}_C(c,c')$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_D(d,d')$.

The set of objects of $D^C$ is the set of all functors $F : C \to D$, and such an object is determined by a collection of functions, namely its function $O_C \to O_D$ on objects and its functions on hom-sets $\mathrm{Hom}_C(c,c') \to \mathrm{Hom}_D(Fc, Fc')$ ; since all sets involvled here are small and the product of small sets indexed by a small set is again small, the set of objects of $D^C$ is again small.

Now let $F,G : C \to D$ be two functors ; the hom-set $D^C(F,G)$ has for elements collections of morphisms $Fc \to Gc$, i.e. elements of the hom-sets of $D$. Thus a natural transformation is an element of the product over all $c \in O_C$ of the hom-sets between $Fc$ and $Gc$, and by the same reasoning we conclude that $D^C(F,G)$ is contained in a small set, thus small.

So why does Mac Lane tell me that the hom-set of a functor category need not be small? Or where is my mistake? Did I misinterpret something? (Page 40, right before the last paragraph.)

Answer (score 10):

Everything you say is correct.  I don't have Mac Lane in front of me at the moment, but I would guess he actually only assumed that $C$ and $D$ were *locally* small, so while each Hom-set is small, the set of objects might be large.

Comment: I see. He actually never mentions small before he says that the hom-set between two functors is not necessarily small, I just assumed he took everything small. Thanks!

Comment: If $C$ is small and $D$ is locally small, then $D^C$ is still locally small (i.e., the hom-sets between functors are small).  But if $C$ can be large (even if locally small), $D^C$ is usually not locally small even if $D$ is small.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Hi, im lookig for a proof of the first statement. Do you know where can I find one?

Comment: @N.Pullbacki: What do you mean by "the first statement"?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey "If $C$ is small and $D$ is locally small, then $D^C$ is still locally small".

Comment: @N.Pullbacki: Just write down the definition of a morphism in $D^C$.  A natural transformation from $F$ to $G$ consists of maps $Fc\to Gc$ for each object $c$ of $C$.  There is a small set of such $c$ since $C$ is small, and for each $c$ there is a small set of maps $Fc\to Gc$ since $D$ is locally small.  So there is a small set of natural transformations from $F$ to $G$.